# MySQL assort categories with title

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if the title is wrong, I couldn't think of a way to correctly word it. Here is the problem I have come across and hopefully somebody can help me with a solution. I have an SQL call that retrieves from a cms table. I am wanting to output the CMS category name and list the pages that are under that category on the page. For example:

```
Home
   Page One
   Page Two
   Page Three
Contact
   Page One
   Page Two
   Page Three
```

Here is what my tables look like using the content above

```
cms
id_cms | id_cms_category | position | active
  1    |        1        |     1    |   1  
  2    |        1        |     1    |   1   
  3    |        1        |     1    |   1   
  4    |        2        |     2    |   1   
  5    |        2        |     2    |   1   
  6    |        2        |     2    |   1    

cms_category_lang
id_cms_category |   name  | description
      1         |  Home   |   NULL
      2         | Contact |   NULL


cms_page_lang
id_cms | title    | content
  1    | Page One | Test Content 1        
  2    | Page Twi | Test Content 2                 
  3    |Page Three| Test Content 3       
  4    | Page One | Test Content 4    
  5    | Page Two | Test Content 5      
  6    |Page Three| Test Content 6
```

I have tried several queries to try to accomplish this, but can't seem to get anything to work.

I have tried to query the titles first and my results returns an array

```
SELECT * FROM cms_category_lang
array 0 =>
      'id_cms_category' = 1
      'name' = Home
      'description' = ''
      1 =>
      'id_cms_category' = 2
      'name' = Contact
      'description' = ''
```

Then I queried the cms_page_lang and got a similar array, but with the values from that table and I tried to join them in the array based off the id_cms_category. I don't think this is the route I am looking for since it didn't echo out correctly. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have done a query to get things from all three tables using LEFT JOIN. The problem I am running into is putting them in that layout on the page. Where the pages that are suppose to be under the Home Category are under the home category and the ones under the contact category are under that category and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f20b2a/3)

I think this will give you the results your looking for.  You can remove the GROUP_CONCAT function if you want each cms_page_lang on its own row

```
SELECT
       ccl.name
       ,GROUP_CONCAT(cpl.title)
FROM cms
LEFT JOIN cms_category_lang AS ccl
  ON cms.id_cms_category = ccl.id_cms_category
LEFT JOIN cms_page_lang AS cpl
  ON cms.id_cms = cpl.id_cms

GROUP BY ccl.name
```